# How to prove $\textrm{Rk}(\psi \circ \varphi) = \textrm{Rk} \varphi \iff \textrm{Im} \varphi \cap \textrm{Ker} \psi = \{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have have been given the following two linear maps:
$\varphi:V \to W$, $\psi: W \to U$.

I am supposed two proof the following equivalence:

$$\textrm{Rk}(\psi \circ \varphi) = \textrm{Rk} \varphi \iff \textrm{Im} \varphi \cap \textrm{Ker} \psi = \{0\}$$

I started by proving the first direction.

$"\Rightarrow" \textrm{Rk}(\psi \circ \varphi) = \textrm{Rk} \varphi$

$\iff$ $\textrm{dim(Im}(\psi \circ \varphi)) = \textrm{dim(Im} (\varphi))$

So now I can conclude that $\vert W \vert = \vert U \vert$, so $\psi$ is a bijective map.

$\Rightarrow$ $\textrm{Ker} \psi= \{0\}$ because only one element maps the $0$.

And because $0 \in W $, therefore $0 \in \textrm{Im} \varphi$, I can conclude

$\Rightarrow \textrm{Im} \varphi \cap \textrm{Ker} \psi = \{0\}$

But from this point on I am stuck. I dont have any ideas on how I should continue with the second direction $"\Leftarrow"$.

Comment: When you say $|W| = |U|$, do you mean $\operatorname{dim} W = \operatorname{dim} U$? If so, I don't think that's necessarily true.

Comment: Yes, in my understanding $|W| = |U|$ equals $\operatorname{dim} W = \operatorname{dim} U$

Comment: A linear map from $V\to W$ does not mean that the map is onto on $W$, so $\dim W$ may not equal $\text{rank}(\varphi)$

Comment: Ok after revisiting the definitions, I did indeed made a mistake. After saying that $\textrm{dim(Im}(\psi \circ \varphi)) = \textrm{dim(Im} (\varphi))$ I can not conclude $\vert W \vert = \vert U \vert$. Do you have any tips on how to improve the proof?

Comment: Why haven't you at least upvoted one of these answers, for example the good answer by Shubham Johri, written almost a year ago ? Think that these people have devoted time to you : it is a way to say them thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$\implies $

By the rank-nullity theorem,$$\text{rank}(\psi\circ\varphi)+\dim\ker(\psi\circ\varphi)=\dim V=\text{rank}(\varphi)+\dim\ker(\varphi)$$Since $\text{rank}(\psi\circ\varphi)=\text{rank}(\varphi)$, we have $\dim\ker(\varphi)=\dim\ker(\psi\circ\varphi)$. We also know that $\ker(\varphi)\subseteq\ker(\psi\circ\varphi)$. Because the two kernels are equidimensional, they are equal. Thus, for $v\in V$,$$(\psi\circ\varphi)(v)=0_U\Longleftrightarrow\varphi(v)=0_W$$Call $\varphi(v)=w\in W$, giving for $w\in\text{Im}(\varphi)$,$$\psi(w)=0_U\Longleftrightarrow w=0_W$$i.e. $\text{Im}(\varphi)\cap\ker(\psi)=\{O_W\}$, as required.

---

$\Longleftarrow$

Let $\{w_1,w_2,...,w_r\}$ be a basis of $\text{Im}(\varphi)\subseteq W$ where $r=\text{rank}(\varphi)$. Clearly, $w_i\ne0_W\implies w_i\notin\ker(\psi)$ and $\psi(w_i)\ne0_U$. We need to show that $\mathcal B=\{\psi(w_i):1\le i\le r\}$ is a basis of $\text{Im}(\psi\circ\varphi)$. Clearly, $\mathcal B$ is a spanning set of $\text{Im}(\psi\circ\varphi)$. To show linear independence of $\psi(w_i)$, consider$$\sum_{i=1}^ra_i\psi(w_i)=\psi\left(\sum_{i=1}^r a_iw_i\right)=0_U$$Thus, $\sum_{i=1}^ra_iw_i\in\text{Im}(\varphi)\cap\ker(\psi)\implies\sum_{i=1}^ra_iw_i=0_W$, which further gives $a_i=0$ because of the linear independence of $w_i$.

Answer (score 0):

You should use basis of each vector space. Let ${v_1,v_2, ..., v_n}$ be a basis of $V$, then $\varphi$ sends it to some set of $n$ vector in $W$. We can make from this set a basis of $\text{Im} \varphi$ which contains $m$ vectors, then adding this basis up to basis of $W$. Then apply $\psi$ to each set and using the hypothesis that $\text{Rk} \varphi = \text{Rk} \psi \circ \varphi$.

Answer (score 0):

($\Rightarrow$) Suppose $Rk(\psi \circ \varphi ) = Rk(\varphi)$. This means the linear map $\psi: \varphi(V) \rightarrow \psi(\varphi(V))$ is map between vector spaces having equal dimension. This map is also surjective by construction, and thus injective.  Hence if one choose $x \in \varphi(V) \cap \ker (\psi)$. One has $\psi(x) =0 \in \psi(\varphi(V))$. But as mentioned, the map $\psi: \varphi(V) \rightarrow \psi(\varphi(V))$ is bijective and so $x=0$ necessarily.

($\Leftarrow$) Suppose $Rk(\psi \circ \varphi ) \neq Rk(\varphi)=n$. We know that we always have $Rk(\psi\circ \varphi) \le Rk(\varphi)$ and hence the hypothesis insist that $Rk(\psi \circ \varphi ) < Rk(\varphi)$. Let $\{v_1,\cdots, v_n\}$ be a basis for $Im(\varphi)$. Then $\{\psi(v_1),\cdots, \psi(v_n)\}$ is a spanning set for $\psi(\varphi(V))$.

This set cannot be linearly independent by assumption. This implies there exist some  scalars not all zero s.t. $$a_1 \psi(v_1)+\cdots +a_n\psi(v_n) = \psi(a_1v_1+\cdots + a_nv_n)=0$$

So $0\neq a_1v_1+\cdots + a_nv_n\in Im(\varphi)$ and $a_1v_1+\cdots + a_nv_n \in Ker(\psi)$. So $Im(\varphi)\cap Ker(\psi)\neq 0$.